# Json parse with DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, json

Im using *DataContractJsonSerializer* for Json parsing.
Please tell me how to parse this json:

```
{"response":[2,{"mid":95001,"date":1360173495,"out":0,"uid":32578013,"read_state":0,"title":"Head","body":"message"}, {"mid":95000,"date":1360173439,"out":0,"uid":32506752,"read_state":0,"title":" Theme ","body":"message2"}]}
```

I can not understand what structure do I need to. I'm trying to write this:

```
[DataContract]
internal class Message
{
    [DataMember]
    public int IntMember { get; set; } 

    [DataMember]
    public List<Messages> response { get; set; }        

    [DataContract]
    protected internal struct Messages
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string mid { get; set; }            
        [DataMember]
        public string uid { get; set; }            
        [DataMember]
        public string date { get; set; }           
        [DataMember]
        public string title { get; set; }     
        [DataMember]
        public string body { get; set; }       
    }
}
```

But this does not work because of 2 at beginning. What to do? Delete this number before parsing it, or you can ignore as it clearly?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it doesn't look like you'll be able to use the built-in serializer to get what you need. The array looks like it is including an integer as its first element that indicates the length of the array, which is not standard JSON and (as you've obviously discovered) means that the array contains a list of heterogeneous elements.

You may have more luck with a more purpose-built JSON library like [JSON.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)

Comment: Right, but your JSON is not compatible with it, so you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Thank issue resolved. With the aid of regular expressions find "unnecessary number" and delete

If you need the number itself:

```
@"(?<=response\D*)\d+"
```

If you need a number with a comma:

```
@"(?<=response\D*)\d[^{]*"
```

And then replace

```
Replace(jsonString, RegEx);
```

Thanks internet, book C # 5.0 and the forum CyberForum